# Query multiple SharePoint lists Using REST API and angular JS

Tags: sharepoint-addin, rest, angularjs

I am using a provider hosted app and developing the app using angular js and SharePoint REST API for fetching List data.

I am facing an issue with calling SharePoint lists through multiple cross domain calls to SharePoint REST API. I have 2 controllers calling the same service on different user interactions. The first call gets the data properly but when the user clicks a button to call second controller on a different user interaction to fetch data from a different list i get a request timed out error. I am initiating the SP.RequestExecutor every time the service is called. I am not sure why this is working when i call the service multiple times through one controller but not when i call the service through another controller. Could you please let me know if the above issue you were facing has been resolved? Below is my code sample.

**Service Call:**

```
var getRequest = function (listTitle) {
 deferred = $q.defer();
  var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
            executor.executeAsync({

                url: query,
                method: "GET",
                headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
                success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                    deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
                },
                error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    deferred.reject(JSON.parse(xhr.body).error);
                }
            }); return deferred.promise;

        };
        return {
            getRequest: getRequest

        };
```

**Controller 1:**

```
app.controller("progressController", ["$scope", "baseSvc", "$q", "$filter",
function ($scope, baseSvc, $q, $filter) {
   $scope.profiles = [];
                     executeOnSPLoaded(function () {
                      $q.all([baseSvc.getRequest('CandidateList'), baseSvc.getRequest('GeneralSearchDocuments')]).then(function (data) {
            $scope.profilesFromSp = data[0].d.results;
           $scope.Candidatedocuments = data[1].d.results;
           $scope.loadData();
            });
   });
```

**Controller 2: (Fails when user clicks button to execute this call)**

```
app.controller("documentsController", ["$scope", "baseSvc", "$q", "$filter",
    function ($scope, baseSvc, $q, $filter) {
            executeOnSPLoaded(function () {
            $q.all([baseSvc.getRequest('GeneralSearchDocuments')]).then(function (data) {
                  $scope.documents = data[0].d.results;

            });
        });
```

**Load SP.js & SP.RequestExecutor**

```
function executeOnSPLoaded(loaded) {

    var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.when(
        //$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js"),
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js"),
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js"),
        $.Deferred(function (deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
        })
    ).done(function () {
        loaded();
          });
}
```

Comment: What is the error in Controller 2?

Comment: Hi Atish, Thanks for your response. I have 2 tabs on my UI. On page load the first controller 1 loads and calls the service properly and gets the data to bind it to my view. When i click on the second tab the controller 2 gets called and requests the service to get data from a different SP list. I see that the call is being made but when the code executes the REST call i get an error message saying "Request aborted or times out". I am not sure if this is happening due to multiple loading of SP.js and SP.RequestExecutor.js files. But when i reload the page on tab 2 it executes and gets data.

Comment: Ya... That could be the reason. You are loading `SP.js` multiple times. That is not needed I guess. Load `sp.js` only once and then call `angular.element(document).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(document, ['Your App Name']);
    });`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You loading `SP.js` and `SP.RequestExecutor.js` in every call to `baseSvc`. That is not needed. Try following

1. Load `SP.js` and `SP.RequestExecutor.js` in document ready
2. Then initialize angular app

## Example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl"));
    var appweburl = decodeURIComponent(getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl"));
    var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";
    $.when(
        //$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js"),
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js"),
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js"),
        $.Deferred(function(deferred) {
            $(deferred.resolve);
        })
    ).done(function() {
        angular.element(document).ready(function() {
            angular.bootstrap(document, ['Your App Name']);
        });
    });
});
```

In the controllers, just call something like

```
$q.all([baseSvc.getRequest('GeneralSearchDocuments')]).then(function(data) {
    $scope.documents = data[0].d.results;
});
```

Meaning remove all `executeOnSPLoaded`.

Also see [Angular's Manual Initialization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/bootstrap)

Comment: Thank you very much Atish this fixed my issue :). Also, i am trying to use CAML query REST API to fetch the files from multiple folders. I have posted my issue in the below link could you please let me know what am i missing here? I followed one of your posts on code project about the same and not able to figure out the issue. Could you please help me with this issue http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/167515/use-rest-api-with-caml-query-to-fetch-the-files-inside-multiple-folders-in-singl