# Use REST API with CAML query to fetch the files inside multiple folders in single REST Call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin, rest, caml-query

I have a scenario where i would like to fetch all the files from multiple folders using REST API. I would like to filter the data in such a way so i can ignore the folders and fetch only the files inside all the files. I have the CAML query to do the recursive all activity but when i integrate with REST API its throwing a Bad request error. I checked the Network tab in IE it seems like the query in my code is not returning any data from REST API and it is failing when i use "GetItems". Could someone please let me know how to integrate CAML query in REST API.

```
 var getContent = function (listTitle) {

                var deferred = $q.defer();

                if (listTitle == 'CandidateReports') {


  var query = appweburl + "_api/SP.AppContextSite("+ hostweburl +")/web/lists/GetByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/GetItems";



                var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);
                executor.executeAsync({

                    url: query,
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose",
                        "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
                        "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose"
                    },
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        query: {
                            __metadata: {
                                type: "SP.CamlQuery"
                            },
                            ViewXml: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> </ViewFields> <QueryOptions> <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /> </QueryOptions> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value> </Eq>   </Where>"
                        }
                    }),
                    success: function (data, textStatus, xhr) {
                        console.log(data);
                        deferred.resolve(JSON.parse(data.body));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        deferred.reject(JSON.parse(xhr.body).error);
                    }
                });

                return deferred.promise;

            };

            return {

                getContent: getContent

            };
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example shows how to retrieve all of the files in a folder.

```
url: http://site url/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('/Folder Name')/Files
method: GET
headers:
    Authorization: "Bearer " + accessToken
    accept: "application/json;odata=verbose" or "application/atom+xml"
```

Does this help? 
[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn292553.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Am I crazy or should you need `Get`, not `Post`?

```
url: query,
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
```

Answer (score 0):

try this... replace this

```
data: JSON.stringify({
                    query: {
                        __metadata: {
                            type: "SP.CamlQuery"
                        },
                        ViewXml: "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> </ViewFields> <QueryOptions> <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' /> </QueryOptions> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value> </Eq>   </Where>"
                    }
                }),
```

with this

```
data: {
        query: {
                "__metadata": {
                    "type": "SP.CamlQuery"
                    },
                    "ViewXml": "<View scope='RecursiveAll'><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='FileLeafRef' /> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> </ViewFields> <Query> <Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' /> <Value Type='Integer'>0</Value> </Eq>   </Where></Query></View>"
                    }
                },
```

There is no need to strigify the header values. Also Including the "View" nodes in the caml is required